# What is wrong with my code? I cannot grasp the concept of

Tags: python, binary, decimal, converters

```
decimal = input("Please insert a number: ")


if decimal > 256:

print "Value too big!"


elif decimal < 1:
    print "Value too small!"

else:
    decimal % 2

binary1 = []
binary0 = []
if decimal % 2 == 0:
    binary1.append[decimal]

else:
    binary0.append[decimal]
print binary1
print binary0
```

So Far, I want to test this code, it says on line 13:

> TypeError: builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute
>   `__getitem__`.

I don't understand why it is wrong.

I would like to convert the decimal number into binary. I only wanted to try and get the first value of the input then store it in a list to use then add it to another list as either a 0, or a 1. And if the input doesn't divide by 2 equally, add a zero. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
binary1.append[decimal]
```

You tried to get an element from the `append` method, hence triggering the error.  Since it's a function or method, you need to use the appropriate syntax to invoke it.

```
binary1.append(decimal)
```

Ditto for the other append call.

Comment: It did work!
If I were to do this for diving each result by 2, is there a faster way, like in 2 or 3 lines? I heard about **2 but wasn't sure, please explain!

Comment: `(number)**2` means take the number to the power of 2. Since you are working with binary then you would want to take 2^(number), so you would want to use `2 ** (number)`. In this case you can just find the biggest number 2^x can equal for your input and then subtract and repeat the process. @Nathaniel

Comment: @nwalsh, pardon? I'm not sure, could you give me an example.

Comment: @Nathaniel will make an answer.

Comment: @nwalsh Thanks. Could you also use `#This is to..`  For explaining each step. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In response to your binary question. It is possible to brute-force your way to a solution quite easily. The thinking behind this is we will take any number N and then subtract N by 2 to the biggest power that will be less than N. For instance.

N = 80

2^6 = 64

In binary this is represented as 1000000.

Now take N - 2^6 to get 16.

Find the biggest power 2 can be applied to while being less than or equal to N.

2^4 = 16

In binary this now represented as 1010000.

For the actual code.

```
bList = []
n = int(raw_input("Enter a number"))
for i in range(n, 0, -1): # we will start at the number, could be better but I am lazy, obviously 2^n will be greater than N
    if 2**i <= n: # we see if 2^i will be less than or equal to N
        bList.append(int( "1" + "0" * i) ) # this transfers the number into decimal
        n -= 2**i # subtract the input from what we got to find the next binary number
        print 2**i 
print sum(bList) # sum the binary together to get final binary answer
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood.... I would like to make a BINARY to DECIMAL converter using dividing by 2 and storing the 1's and 0's...

Comment: @Nathaniel whoops. Okay I will make an answer for this later then.

Comment: @Nathaniel where does it say that you wanted binary to decimal? Storing 1's and 0's makes it converting decimal to binary, which is what you are attempting to do in your original post